# Problema con Input tipo texto de formulario en laravel con jquery

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, laravel, ajax

lo que he hecho es un input de tipo texto que funcione similar al buscador de google (me muestre mientras escribo los resultados coincidentes que encuentra en la base de datos)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y cuando se da click en una opción esta se convierte en el valor del input de texto
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que no he conseguido hacer es que el valor que muestre en el input al usuario cuando selecciona una herramienta sea así cómo está, pero que el valor que me llegue a la base de datos sea el id de esa herramienta...
Eso es en lo que necesito ayuda.
Voy a compartir mi código:

`

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Search" name="herramientas_id">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('empleados') }}
        {{ Form::select('empleados_id', $empleados, $registrosalida->empleados_id, ['class' => 'form-control' . ($errors->has('empleados_id') ? ' is-invalid' : ''), 'placeholder' => 'Empleados Id']) }}
        {!! $errors->first('empleados_id', '<div class="invalid-feedback">:message</div>') !!}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('Fecha Salida') }}
        {{ Form::datetimelocal('FechaSalida', $registrosalida->FechaSalida, ['class' => 'form-control' . ($errors->has('FechaSalida') ? ' is-invalid' : ''), 'placeholder' => 'Fechasalida']) }}
        {!! $errors->first('FechaSalida', '<div class="invalid-feedback">:message</div>') !!}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('ObservacionesSalida') }}
        {{ Form::text('ObservacionesSalida', $registrosalida->ObservacionesSalida, ['class' => 'form-control' . ($errors->has('ObservacionesSalida') ? ' is-invalid' : ''), 'placeholder' => 'ObservacionesSalida']) }}
        {!! $errors->first('ObservacionesSalida', '<div class="invalid-feedback">:message</div>') !!}
    </div>
   

</div>
<div class="box-footer mt20">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Ingresar Salida</button>
</div>
```

`

Este es mi script:

```js
<script>
    $('#Search').autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response){
            $.ajax({
                url: '{{route('buscar.herramienta')}}',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    term: request.term
                },
                success: function(data){
                    response(data)
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

**Y esta es mi función del controlador en laravel:**

```
    public function herramienta(Request $request)
{
    $term = $request->get('term');
    $querys = Herramienta::where('Nombre','LIKE','%'.$term.'%')->orWhere('IdInterno','LIKE','%'.$term.'%')->get();
    $data = [];
    foreach($querys as $querys){
        $data[]=[
            'label'=> $querys->IdInterno.$querys->Nombre
        ];
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Otro detalle es que si hago la inserción tal y con el dato que me guarda el input text me da este error en laravel y mysql:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Y bueno lo que necesito hacer es guardar en la base de datos ese id del nombre de la herramienta seleccionada en el input text del formulario y que en el input text se vea reflejada el nombre de la herramienta para el usuario que usa el formulario.

Screenshot repuesta al amigo Heyner:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Cambia tu llenado del objeto data y agrega el value de esta forma

```
$data[]=[
        'label'=> $querys->IdInterno.$querys->Nombre,
        'value'=>$querys->IdInterno
    ];
```

El problema está en que de la forma que lo tienes, le está asignado el texto al value del input y al llegar a la bd llega eso mismo, texto y ahi lo que espera es un Integer

EJEMPLO DE COMO SE CONSTRUYE EN PHP

```
$response = array();
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ){
   $response[] = array("value"=>$row['id'],"label"=>$row['name']);
 }

 echo json_encode($response);
```

te dejo el enlace de esta info aqui tambien
https://makitweb.com/jquery-ui-autocomplete-with-php-and-ajax/

Comment: Hola gracias por la ayuda, lo que sucede es que el  `IdInterno` no es el id numérico del registro, el id numérico del registro lo identifico cómo `id` solamente, pero igualmente apliqué tu código con el `id` que identifica el registro: `$data[]=['label'=> $querys->IdInterno.$querys->Nombre,'value'=>$querys->id];`
Ahora el problema es que en el input se muestra como un numérico para el usuario que ve el formulario y lo que necesito es que en el input se muestre el nombre de la herramienta para el usuario y que el valor que me llegue en la BD sea el `id` de ese registro/Dejo una foto en el post

Comment: si, yo puse ese nombre de Idinterno asumiendo que era tu id, pero claro ahi iria el ID del registro, ahora bien antes de retornar intenta hacer un DD() a ver si se envia correctamente, ya que deberia agregarte el texto normalmente y asignar el value